# Ati Radeon HD 4xxx driver wont install

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, radeon, amd-graphics

When I attempt to install the file from the amd site:

```
justin@Home-PC:~/Downloads/amd$ ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

I recieve the following error

> error: Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer _64a:none:4.13.0-32-generic:)

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine 16.04. Same issue on xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu 16.04 does not support legacy Catalyst drivers. The X server version is higher.

AMD dropped support for Catalyst. You'd better use the open source Radeon driver.

Comment: Where would I find those

Comment: It is included in the 16.04 iso. The driver should be automatically installed.